# Force footer to be alway in the bottom in CSS

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm generating a left side menu and it's populated with some objects. The problem is that I need to position my footer **allways** at the bottom of the page (no matter how many objects there are in the menu).

I'm using absolute position and bottom tag but the result is not the correct one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzC7U.png)

This is the CSS code I'm using for it:

```css
/*Footer*/
#mainfooter{
    font-size: 16px; 
    background:#dd3035;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
/*Left menu*/
.list-group{
    padding-left: initial;
}

.list-group-item{
    background-color: #dd3035;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    list-style:none;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="kid_list">
 <div class="list-group">
  <ul style="padding-left: initial;">
   <t t-if="kids">
    <t t-foreach="kids" t-as="kid">
     <li class="list-group-item">
      <a t-attf-href="/user/{{kid.id}}">
       <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>
       <span class="nav-text">
        <t t-esc="kid.name" />
       </span>
      </a>
     </li>
    </t>
   </t>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="mainfooter">
 <small>Copyright 2019-2020, Coas Education Website</small>
</div>
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks for reading!

Comment: The code you provided works perfectly to keep the bottom bar fixed to the bottom. I think that there is other css blocking this functionality, try checking in developer tab and look in the style tab wich code is disabled and why..

Answer (score 2):

You should change `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;` for mainfooter

```css
#mainfooter {
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #dd3035;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.list-group {
  padding-left: initial;
}

.list-group-item {
  background-color: #dd3035;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="kid_list">
  <div class="list-group">
    <ul style="padding-left: initial;">
      <div t-if="kids">
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">test</li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="mainfooter">
  <small>Copyright 2019-2020, Coas Education Website</small>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the position to fixed. something like the below:

```
#mainfooter{
    font-size: 16px; 
    background:#dd3035;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use position:fixed for your footer
ex

```
#mainfooter{
    font-size: 16px; 
    background:#dd3035;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use flex-box like in the following snippet:

```js
// Not required!
// This is just to demo functionality.

var add = document.getElementById("add");

add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo."
  document.getElementById("content").appendChild(p)
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh; /* Avoid the IE 10-11 `min-height` bug. */
}
.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* Prevent Chrome, Opera, and Safari from letting these items shrink to smaller than their content's default minimum size. */
  padding: 20px;
}
.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* Prevent Chrome, Opera, and Safari from letting these items shrink to smaller than their content's default minimum size. */
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #FFF
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="content">
  <h1>Sticky Footer with Flexbox</h1>
  <p><button id="add">Add Content</button></p>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  Footer 
</footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing position: absolute for position:fixed resolved the problem.
Thanks for all replies.

Comment: Please accept the answer that helped you rather than posting your own answer